# VBA code to extract API URL's result in Excel

Tags: json, api, excel, url, vba

I have a API URL to get a simple result in JSON `{"visit":"0","sales":"0"}`.

The problem is that the URL works only for 1 parameter at a time and I have hundreds of entries to map.

Below is the URL

```
http://<Website>/lms/lmsapi.php?mobileno=<10digits-mobileNumber>&leaddate=<yyyy-mm-dd>
```

I just need to change the values between "<>".

I have the excel file ready with all the entries and any new entry will create a custom URL replacing the above values.

I need a `VBA script` to get the result in the `Excel` file in the cell adjacent to the entry.

Comment: What kind of API are you using REST ? do you want the visit and sales result in different cells or in the same cell.

Comment: I am not sure about the API type as the URL is given by one of my Business Clients. Results in different cells would be helpful, but can also work with same cell entry.

Comment: I am using WEBSERVICE formula for now, but the problem is that the result changes to #VALUE after automatic recalculation in every few minutes and I have to manually process the formula again.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub XMLHttpTest()

    ' Dim Variables
    Dim XMLHttp     As Object
    Dim ApiUrl      As String, ApiRequestType As String, ApiUser As String
    Dim ApiPwd      As String
    Dim bolAsync    As Boolean
    Dim ApiMsg                  ' <----mostly for Post
    Dim r           As Range

    'create Microsoft XML HTTP Objekt
    Set XMLHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    'Set ScriptControl for parsing JSON
    Set ScriptControl = CreateObject("ScriptControl"): ScriptControl.Language = "JScript"


    'Loop through every Used Cell in A
    With ActiveSheet
        For Each r In Intersect(.Range("a:a"), .UsedRange) ' <- i assume your urls are saved in column A if not change a:a to whatever you need

            ' Add the parameters for our request
            ApiRequestType = "GET"
            ApiUrl = r.Value
            bolAsync = False
            ApiUser = ""
            ApiPwd = ""
            ApiMsg = ""

         ' execute Request
            Call XMLHttp.Open(ApiRequestType, ApiUrl, bolAsync, ApiUser, ApiPwd)
            Call XMLHttp.send(ApiMsg)
            MsgBox XMLHttp.responseText
            If XMLHttp.Status <> 200 Then
                MsgBox "The Request returned " & XMLHttp.Status & XMLHttp.statusText

            Else
                Set jsonDecode = ScriptControl.Eval("(" + XMLHttp.responseText + ")")
                Cells(r.Row, r.Column + 1).Value = jsonDecode.visit
                Cells(r.Row, r.Column + 2).Value = jsonDecode.sales
            End If


        Next
    End With

    MsgBox "Request successfull."

End Sub
```

Sry, that it took so long but i had some busy days. 
I think the above code should solve your problem.
Be sure to only use it on apis you trust since the ScriptControl could take JAVA commands and execute them so keep that in mind
If you want to accept other status messages then 200 just change

```
If XMLHttp.Status <> 200
```

to fit your needs

Comment: Thanks! Will try today!

Comment: getting error " Run-Time error '-2147467259 (80004005)': Method 'open' of object 'IXMLHTTPRequest' failed "

Comment: What parameters are given to open()